# Quartus II : can't determine definition of operator ""<=""

Tags: fpga, vga

I am stucked with some VHDL code.

I am trying to compile this:

```
entity ball is
    port(video_on : in std_logic;
        pixel_x,pixel_y : in std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);
        obj3_r,obj3_g,obj3_b : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        obj3_on : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture arch of ball is


-- definimos dimension de izquierda a derecha
constant ball_l : integer :=800;
constant ball_r : integer :=815;

-- definimos dimension de arriba a abajo
constant ball_top : integer :=502;
constant ball_bottom : integer :=522;


begin

obj3_on <= '1' when (ball_l <=pixel_x) and (pixel_x <= ball_r) and (ball_top <= pixel_y) and (pixel_y <= ball_bottom) else 
            '0';

obj3_r <= (others => '0');
obj3_g <= "0111";
obj3_b <= (others => '0');

end arch;
```

Quartus II is showing this error : can't determine definition of operator "<="; at the line where the WHEN STATEMENT is used. 
I have no idea what the problem is.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use relational operators on signals of type `std_logic_vector` which doesn't have them defined. You can make it work by one of the following:

- Use the `unsigned` type defined in `ieee.numeric_std`. It is the standard way to interpret arrays in a numeric context. Either declare your port signals as `unsigned` or use the type conversion functions in each comparison.
- With VHDL-2008 support, use the `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned` package which adds unsigned numeric semantics to `std_logic_vector`.

Don't use the non-standard `std_logic_arith` which is an earlier package similar to `numeric_std_unsigned`.

You should also use `natural` instead of `integer` for the constants since there is no operator defined for comparing `unsigned` with `integer`.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!!  Finally I added the numeric_std.all and used the type conversion function in each comparison.
But how I know which type are available the relational operators for?
Is there any list I can use with a resume?

Comment: You can find the contents of all standard packages online. Browse through them to see what is available. This is the best way to learn this as most books don't explore the standard library in detail.